# Postgresql aggregate array bracket removal

Tags: postgresql, array-agg

How do i remove the brackets {} from an Array_AGG query output?

```
ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT(SGL.short_name))
```

from this `{01,02}`
to this `01|02|`

thanks!

Comment: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `string_agg` instead.

```
string_agg(DISTINCT SGL.short_name, '|')
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `array_to_string()`:

```
ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT(SGL.short_name)), '|')
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the order of the output from  01|02|03|04|05|KG|PK  to PK|KG|01|02|03|04|05   ?

Comment: @user3263892 . . . Yes, you would add an `order by` clause.